# jstl- Difference between these two codes

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I have this code

```
<fmt:formatDate value="<%=new java.util.Date() %>" var="now" type="both"/>
<c:out value="${now }" />
```

which gives error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
```

Now I have this code:

```
<c:set var="dd" value="<%=new java.util.Date() %>" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${dd}" var="now" type="both"/>
<c:out value="${now }" />
```

Which gives correct output:

```
Mar 22, 2017 10:09:24 PM
```

So my question is what is different in these two codes.

**Edit 1:**
Complete code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
The above mentioned codes were inserted here.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Both work for me! Something else is wrong in your JSP! Show the complete JSP code!

Comment: @jmmontero edited...please check

Answer (score 0):

Both formatting work just fine! I don't understand why you are having problems:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Format 1</h1>
<fmt:formatDate value="<%=new java.util.Date() %>" var="now" type="both"/>
<c:out value="${now }" /> 
<h1>Format 2</h1>
<c:set var="dd" value="<%=new java.util.Date() %>" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${dd}" var="now" type="both"/>
<c:out value="${now }" /> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what application server you are running?

Comment: I'm using Tomcat v9.0

Comment: Did that work for you? Or still having problems?